# Converting a pixel coordinate in GeoTIFF to a latitude and longitude?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, web-mercator

I have a GeoTIFF with the following meta information:

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
```

How to I find the geographic coordinate (lat, lon) in Web Mercator of a pixel in the image (e.g. x=500, y=600)

Comment: That's just the projection information - the metadata report should also contain an origin coordinate and cell dimensions. Can you add that information?

Comment: Are you opposed to using a programming language to get the answer?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that you use python gdal.
The Geotransform object contains the coordinates of the pixel at the bottom left corner and x and y pixel size. The units are specified in the projection object that you posted.
Since you have a projected reference system, you have meter units [See description of your coordinate system here](https://epsg.io/3857)
Once you have the Geotransform information it is easy to get to the desired pixel coordinates.

```
import gdal
tif = gdal.Open(my_tiff)
gt = tif.GetGeoTransform()
```

For example:

```
gt
>>>(1100000.0, 25.0, 0.0, -4200000.0, 0.0, -25.0)
```

We can extract the values we need:

```
x_min = gt[0]
x_size = gt[1]
y_min = gt[3]
y_size = gt[5]
```

And use them to calculate the coordinates of a given pixel:

```
mx, my = 500, 600  #coord in map units, as in question
px = mx * x_size + x_min #x pixel
py = my * y_size + y_min #y pixel
```

Comment: Is the .GetGeotransform() function should be GetGeoTransform() (capitalize T)?

Comment: yes, thank you Nick, I have edited