# AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute '__getattr__'

Tags: python, coordinates, attributeerror

I have made a PyQt application where I load UAV images and I display the coordinates (lat, long) according to where the mouse pointer shows. I use this code: [Converting a pixel coordinate in GeoTIFF to a latitude and longitude?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299571/converting-a-pixel-coordinate-in-geotiff-to-a-latitude-and-longitude) . When running the code, I get this error. Any ideas?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/just_learning/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 224, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/just_learning/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 3005, in mouse_move
    self.set_message(s)
  File "code.py", line 151, in set_message
    gt = tif.GetGeotransform()
  File "/home/just_learning/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osgeo/gdal.py", line 2045, in <lambda>
    __getattr__ = lambda self, name: _swig_getattr(self, Dataset, name)
  File "/home/just_learning/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osgeo/gdal.py", line 74, in _swig_getattr
    return _swig_getattr_nondynamic(self, class_type, name, 0)
  File "/home/just_learning/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osgeo/gdal.py", line 69, in _swig_getattr_nondynamic
    return object.__getattr__(self, name)
AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

This is the code:

```
. . . 

import gdal
tif = gdal.Open('UAV.tif')
gt = tif.GetGeotransform()

x_min = gt[0]
x_size = gt[1]
y_min = gt[3]
y_size = gt[5]

mx, my = x, y # I feed x,y from pixel coordinates
px = mx * x_size + x_min #x pixel
py = my * y_size + y_min #y pixel

. . .
```

The solutions that I have found, such as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28530982/why-is-object-getattr-missing does not guide me to a solution...

Update(27/09/2021): I tried this code, which seems to work:

```
import rasterio

with rasterio.open('rasters/raster.tif') as map_layer:
    pixels2coords = map_layer.xy(x,y)  #I feed x,y with pixel coordinates
    print(pixels2coords)
```

(source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52443906/pixel-array-position-to-lat-long-gdal-python)

What modifications should I do on the above code in order to feed it with 'WGS 84' and output coordinates in the format: 00.00000, 0.000000 ?? (Obviously not zeros but you understand the format... )

Update(29/09/2021): I need to transform WGS84 to decimal degrees...